# Java EE duplicates session over the network

Tags: java, proxy, network-protocols

I've developed a Java EE Sprint Maps Application with realm. The problem is that when I logged in a computer, every computer on the network I am getting the same session as the first computer that logged in.

This network have a proxy in the 8080 port.

This is very weird, why is this happening?

Comment: it is possible that the cookie is saved in the proxy?

Comment: you can edit your question instead of commenting your own question. I see you just started on Stackoverflow, so check this out http://stackoverflow.com/faq enjoy ;)

Comment: what application server are you running?

Comment: How do you know it is the same session?